# Someone asked "10,900,000 (10.9 million) is 299% more than x". What's the value of x?

Tags: percentages

Someone in the office asked this question, and we are attempting to solve it (it seems to be a friendly brain teaser around the work place).

We tried to do a more consumable method where the values weren't scary high.

We tried saying `5 is 50% more of x`.

Our equation would be `5 / 0.5 = 10`

If we follow that style of equation, then

`10,900,000 / 2.99 = 3,645,484.949832775919732`

Is `3,645,484.949832775919732` correct?

If not, can someone walk us through the answer?

Comment: You are saying $5$ is $50\%$ more of $10$? Do you mean $5$ is $50\%$ more 'than' $10/3$ or do you mean $5$ is $50\%$ of $10$?

Comment: Where do you work where markup and margin aren't used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's incorrect.  You have to divide by $3.99$ not $2.99$.  You would be correct if the question said, "$10,000,000$ is $299\%$ *of* $x$," instead of $299\%$ *more than* $x$.  Just as $100\%$ more means twice as much, $300\%$ more means $4$ times as much, and this is a just a tad less.

Generally "$p$ percent more" means as much, plus another $p$ percent.

Answer (score 1):

To say that "$y$ is $a\%$ more than $x$" means that "$y$ equals $x$ plus $a\%$ of $x$". That is,

$$y = x + \left( \dfrac a{100} \right) x$$.

Thus if $5$ is $50\%$ more than $x$, then
$$5 = x + \left( \dfrac {50}{100} \right) x =  \dfrac 32 x$$ so that $x = \dfrac {10}3$.

You need to solve
$$10900000 = x + \left( \dfrac{299}{100} \right)x = \dfrac{399}{100}x$$ for $x$.